# How to enable recursive reading in imapla

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, mapreduce, impala

I need to query the hourly map reduce batch results from Imapala

```
output directory structure will be 
/data/access/web1/2015/Jan/day1/09/part-r-00000
/data/access/web1/2015/Jan/day1/09/part-r-00001
...
/data/access/web1/2015/Jan/day1/20/part-r-00000
/data/access/web1/2015/Jan/day1/20/part-r-00001
...
/data/access/web1/2015/Jan/day2/01/part-r-00000
...
/data/access/web1/2015/Jan/day30/18/part-r-00000
....
```

Is it possible to create an impala table to read the data from `/data/access/web1/*` directory (including sub directories)

By default impala is not querying the data from sub directories.

How to enable recursive reading in impala?

Work around is to create a partition table in impala.
But partition table doesn't fit our requirement.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As of now recursive reading of files from sub directories under the TABLE LOCATION is not supported in Impala. Example: If a table is created with location '/home/data/input/'

and if the directory structure is as follows:

```
/home/data/input/a.txt 
/home/data/input/b.txt
 /home/data/input/subdir1/x.txt
 /home/data/input/subdir2/y.txt
```

then Impala can query from following files only

```
/home/data/input/a.txt
 /home/data/input/b.txt
```

Following files are not queried

```
/home/data/input/subdir1/x.tx
 /home/data/input/subdir2/y.txt
```

As a alternative solution, you can read the data from Hive and insert into a Final Hive Table.

Create an Impala view on top of this table for Interactive or Reporting queries.

You can set this feature in Hive using below configuration settings.

Hive supports subdirectory scan with options

SET mapred.input.dir.recursive=true;

and

SET hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=true;

Answer (score -2):

Checkout Hive [external tables](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ExternalTables):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_external_table (c1 INT, c2 STRING, c3 TIMESTAMP)
  LOCATION '/data/access/web1';
```

Impala will read data from the given HDFS directory recursively.

When you add new files to the HDFS directory, call `refresh my_external_table;` on Impala to notify Impala about the new data.

Comment: I tried the above and it didn't work. Impala doesn't seem to have the same feature as that of hive of reading directories recursively.